# when to use ListPath (querydsl)?

Tags: java, querydsl

I have a current code that use [listPath](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/ListPath.html), but I encounter problems to understand it in order to add changes.

I didn't find useful informations when searching in google.

Any explanation when and how to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example join a `ListPath`

Given the entity metamodel:

```
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QCat extends EntityPathBase<Cat> {
    // Other fields omitted for brevity

    public final ListPath<Cat, QCat> kittens = this.<Cat, QCat>createList("kittens", Cat.class, QCat.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);
```

You could for example do:

```
query().from(cat, cats)
           .innerJoin(cat.kittens, kitten).where(kitten.name.eq("Kitty"))
           .select(cat).fetch();
```